# How to render Sitecore Forms from cshtml?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have query on rendering Sitecore Form.

Can I simply render it by following code on my cshtml ?

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Forms/Mvc Form" , new { DataSource = "/sitecore/Forms/Contact" })
```

As it is not working for me.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleague **Dirk Schäfauer** helped me with a way.

Here it is

```
@Html.Action("Load", "FormBuilder", new RouteValueDictionary() { {"id", "formid.ToString()"}})
```

Tested and working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing inherently special about the Experience Forms rendering. It is a rendering like any other Controller Rendering, custom or otherwise. Yes, the Controller itself does call a Sitecore pipeline, but there is nothing stopping you from doing that in your own custom Controller Rendering either.

[image: MVC Form Rendering]

If you want to statically bind a rendering in a View, then you can do this like any other [statically bound rendering in Sitecore](https://ctor.io/specify-datasource-item-of-a-statically-binded-rendering/) and by also passing in the `Datasource` parameter to specify the ID or path of the Form item.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{6b5b0fe6-5c85-4487-ba7e-f8c2ecc186a8}", new { DataSource = "{4bedad68-958d-4ea3-aee4-9e6d032eccfa}" })

@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{6b5b0fe6-5c85-4487-ba7e-f8c2ecc186a8}", new { DataSource = "/sitecore/Forms/Rob Test Form" })

@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Forms/Mvc Form", new { DataSource = "/sitecore/Forms/Rob Test Form" })
```

The GUID above is the `Item ID` of the `MVC Form` Controller Rendering item. You can also pass in the path to both the Rendering and the Datasource.

[image]

Tested in Sitecore 9.2 and 9.3.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is what finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method which returns the HTML for the form. The `formItemId` is the ID of the form datasource ID.

```
public MvcHtmlString RenderForm(Guid formItemId)
{
    var form = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(IDs.MvcFormRendering));

    var formRendering = new Rendering
    {
        DataSource = formItemId.ToString(),
        RenderingItemPath = form.Paths.FullPath
    };

    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline("mvc.renderRendering", new RenderRenderingArgs(formRendering, stringWriter));
    return new MvcHtmlString(stringWriter.ToString());
}
```

In the View you can call it with `@Html.Raw(RenderForm(formItemId))`.

Tested on Sitecore 9.1.

Comment: Wasn't able to get this to work in 9.3.